# JavaScript Drag&Drop without childNodes of parent DIV?

Tags: javascript, dom

### TL;DR

I'd like to drag & drop `span`s from one container `div` to a target `div` and back but not being the draggable `span`s valid drop targets themselves.

### Description

I'm bulding an interactive tournament bracket app and I do struggle with setting the elements valid drop targets. I have a `border`ed `div` with `#team-container` on the right where all the draggable team `span`s (`.draggable-team`) are placed ([screen snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIOgr.png)).

I used [this](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/web-apis/javascript-drag-and-drop/) tutorial and managed to get it working perfectly but there is also an unintended behaviour.

The valid drop targets are indicated by `.drop-target` and I add event listeners to all of these via

```
const dropTargets = document.querySelectorAll(".drop-target");

dropTargets.forEach(dropTarget => {
    // dropTarget.addEventListener(...);
});
```

Unfortunately, the items I like to place via drag & drop are also set as valid drop targets ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHCc7.png)). I think that is due to the `querySelectorAll` I use as the `#team-container` is a `.drop-target` too, so the teams can be returned there when necessary. The returned NodeList object does contain the `#team-container` with its `childNodes` containing the draggable teams which might be the cause of trouble.

Any idea how to prevent the childs (the teams I like to drag & drop) from being a valid drop target just by being placed into a `div` that also is a valid drop target? Every help much appreciated! Thanks!

### Edit 1

- Removed First version with the issue. Possible nesting of draggable team spans is undesirable.
- I have kind of solved my problem with if clauses checking if the drop target also is a `draggable-team` or contains `.name`. Is there a more elegant way of preventing the draggable team spans from being selectable as drop target?

### Edit 2

- Added first version snippet here and removed links to jsfiddle.net

```js
addDragListeners();

const dropTargets = document.querySelectorAll('.drop-target');

dropTargets.forEach((dropTarget) => {
  dropTarget.addEventListener('dragenter', dragEnter);
  dropTarget.addEventListener('dragover', dragOver);
  dropTarget.addEventListener('dragleave', dragLeave);
  dropTarget.addEventListener('drop', drop);
});

function addDragListeners() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.draggable-team');
  items.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener('dragstart', dragStart);
  });
}

function dragStart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id);
  setTimeout(() => {
    e.target.classList.add('hide');
  }, 0);
}

function dragEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('drag-over');
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add('drag-over');
}

function dragLeave(e) {
  e.target.classList.remove('drag-over');
}

function drop(e) {
  let dropTarget = e.target;
  dropTarget.classList.remove('drag-over');

  let id = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
  let draggable = document.getElementById(id);

  if (dropTarget.id === 'team-container') {
    draggable.classList.remove('dragged-team');
  } else {
    draggable.classList.add('dragged-team');
  }

  dropTarget.appendChild(draggable);

  draggable.classList.remove('hide');
}
```

```css
/* ==================== GLOBAL ==================== */

:root {
  --text-white: #aaaaaa;
  --text-pale: #505050;
  --team-background: #1e1e1e;
  --background: #303030;
  --blue: #003865;
  --bracket-line: 4px solid #ffffff;
}

html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--background);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* ==================== BRACKET ==================== */

.bracket-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  column-gap: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}


/* ----- MATCHES ----- */

.match-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.match {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.team-names {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.match-number {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  color: var(--text-white);
}

.top-number,
.top-name {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--text-pale);
}

.number {
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  min-width: 2.1rem;
  color: var(--team-background);
  background-color: var(--text-white);
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.name {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: var(--text-white);
  background-color: var(--team-background);
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  min-width: 10rem;
}


/* ==================== DRAG & DROP ==================== */

#team-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 50vh;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}

#team-container>span {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 2.5rem;
}

.draggable-team {
  cursor: move;
}

.dragged-team {
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.drag-over {
  background-color: var(--blue);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <article class="bracket-container">
    <div class="match-column">
      <div class="match">
        <span class="seed-number">
            <span class="number top-number">1</span>
        <span class="number bottom-number">4</span>
        </span>
        <span class="team-names">
            <span class="drop-target name top-name"></span>
        <span class="drop-target name bottom-name"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="match">
        <span class="seed-number">
            <span class="number top-number">2</span>
        <span class="number bottom-number">3</span>
        </span>
        <span class="team-names">
            <span class="drop-target name top-name"></span>
        <span class="drop-target name bottom-name"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="match-column">
      <div class="match">
        <span class="seed-number">
            <span class="number top-number">1</span>
        <span class="number bottom-number">2</span>
        </span>
        <span class="team-names">
            <span class="drop-target name top-name"></span>
        <span class="drop-target name bottom-name"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <div id="team-container" class="drop-target">
    <span class="draggable-team name" id="team1" draggable="true">Team1</span>
    <span class="draggable-team name" id="team2" draggable="true">Team2</span>
    <span class="draggable-team name" id="team3" draggable="true">Team3</span>
    <span class="draggable-team name" id="team4" draggable="true">Team4</span>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

- Added second snippet with improved version here

```js
addDragListeners();

const dropTargets = document.querySelectorAll(".drop-target");

dropTargets.forEach(dropTarget => {
  dropTarget.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter);
  dropTarget.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver);
  dropTarget.addEventListener("dragleave", dragLeave);
  dropTarget.addEventListener("drop", drop);
});

function addDragListeners() {
  let items = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable-team");
  items.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener("dragstart", dragStart);
  });
}

function dragStart(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", e.target.id);
  setTimeout(() => {
    e.target.classList.add("hide");
  }, 0);
}

function dragEnter(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add("drag-over");
}

function dragOver(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.classList.add("drag-over");
}

function dragLeave(e) {
  e.target.classList.remove("drag-over");
}

function drop(e) {
  let dropTarget = e.target;
  dropTarget.classList.remove("drag-over");

  let id = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  let draggable = document.getElementById(id);

  // Move draggable back to tem-container if dropTarget is not empty
  if (dropTarget.textContent != "") {
    resetToTeamContainer(e);
  } else {
    // Remove class dragged-team when put back to team-container
    if (dropTarget.id === "team-container") {
      draggable.classList.remove("dragged-team");
    } else {
      draggable.classList.add("dragged-team");
    }

    // If dropped in draggable team, place back in team-container and remove
    // class dragged-team
    if (dropTarget.classList.contains("draggable-team")) {
      resetToTeamContainer(e);
    } else {
      dropTarget.appendChild(draggable);
    }
  }

  // display the draggable element
  draggable.classList.remove("hide");
}

function resetToTeamContainer(e) {
  let id = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  let draggable = document.getElementById(id);
  draggable.classList.remove("dragged-team");
  document.querySelector("#team-container").appendChild(draggable);
}
```

```css
/* ==================== GLOBAL ==================== */

:root {
  --text-white: #aaaaaa;
  --text-pale: #505050;
  --team-background: #1e1e1e;
  --background: #303030;
  --blue: #003865;
  --bracket-line: 4px solid #ffffff;
}

html {
  font-size: 14px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: var(--background);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* ==================== BRACKET ==================== */

.bracket-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  column-gap: 0.5rem;
  margin-left: 1rem;
}


/* ----- MATCHES ----- */

.match-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.match {
  display: flex;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.team-names {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.match-number {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  color: var(--text-white);
}

.top-number,
.top-name {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--text-pale);
}

.number {
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  min-width: 2.1rem;
  color: var(--team-background);
  background-color: var(--text-white);
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.name {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: var(--text-white);
  background-color: var(--team-background);
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  min-width: 10rem;
}


/* ==================== DRAG & DROP ==================== */

#team-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  height: 50vh;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  border: 3px solid #000000;
}

#team-container>span {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  text-align: center;
  max-height: 2.5rem;
}

.draggable-team {
  cursor: move;
}

.dragged-team {
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}

.drag-over {
  background-color: var(--blue);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <article class="bracket-container">
    <div class="match-column">
      <div class="match">
        <span class="seed-number">
            <span class="number top-number">1</span>
        <span class="number bottom-number">4</span>
        </span>
        <span class="team-names">
            <span class="drop-target name top-name"></span>
        <span class="drop-target name bottom-name"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div class="match">
        <span class="seed-number">
            <span class="number top-number">2</span>
        <span class="number bottom-number">3</span>
        </span>
        <span class="team-names">
            <span class="drop-target name top-name"></span>
        <span class="drop-target name bottom-name"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="match-column">
      <div class="match">
        <span class="seed-number">
            <span class="number top-number">1</span>
        <span class="number bottom-number">2</span>
        </span>
        <span class="team-names">
            <span class="drop-target name top-name"></span>
        <span class="drop-target name bottom-name"></span>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>

  <div id="team-container" class="drop-target">
    <span class="draggable-team name" id="team1" draggable="true">Team1</span>
    <span class="draggable-team name" id="team2" draggable="true">Team2</span>
    <span class="draggable-team name" id="team3" draggable="true">Team3</span>
    <span class="draggable-team name" id="team4" draggable="true">Team4</span>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

- **Remaining question:**
  Is there a way to prevent the draggable `span`s from being a valid drop target?

Comment: Please provide a JSFIDDEL/plunker

Comment: I did add fiddles of the past and current status. Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: Sorry, you should actually post the code here see [ask] and how to post a [mcve]. If those links happen to fail then this question is useless for future readers.

Comment: Well, I just did not know one can provide a snippet directly in the question. I hope now things are settled.